# Does smoke make spells invisible too?

Tags: dota-2

I was wondering if enemies can see all spells casted in smoke or its active parts.

For example. Wisps spirits on a smoked Wisp, Abbadons Shield, Lich Shield, etc.

Which spells are visible/readable while the hero itself is smoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All spells that are just buffs/debuffs vanish with the hero. This would include abilities like Abaddon's Aphotic Shield, Lich's Ice Armor, Tusk's Walrus PUNCH!, Treant's Living Armor, Ogre Magi's Bloodlust, etc.

Spells that affect the environment would remain visible though. This would include spells like Io's Spirits, Batrider's Firefly, Doom's Scorched Earth, Sand King's Sandstorm and Epicenter, Crystal Maiden's Freezing Field, Luna's Eclipse, all of Razor's stuff, etc.

More "targeted" spells would obviously be visible like all of Skywrath Mage, Disruptor, Lich, Lion, Lina, and Tinker's stuff.

Also summons would obviously be visible like Pugna/Witch Doctor/Venomancer's wards, Warlock/Tusk/Lycan's summons, etc.

The only ones I'm really unsure about are Gyrocopter's Rocket Barrage and Clockwerk's Battery Assault. I'll try to do some testing on those.

Comment: that's how i pictured it. but how about Ion Shell from Dark Seer. It's a buff and dmg deal. if dark seer picks up an invis rune nothing is visible (you get dmg from nowhere standing next to him). in smoked form does the enemy unit not get any visual feedback too?

Comment: @Wandang: Yeah, smoke would look the same as if you turned invisible with the effect on.